# Github API - How can i get list of Pull Requests for a specific push event?

Tags: github, github-api

i'm trying to understand how can I easily get all pull requests belonging to a specific push event (let's say to a main branch).

From the push event i do get list of commits:

```
   "commits":[
      {
         "id":"ac7196c04ba24f180d37d77209ae92d38ee9c222",
         "tree_id":"9a4abe48ace9e76d561be86ae822a39ff23456de",
         "distinct":false,
         "message":"Update x.txt",
         "timestamp":"2022-11-21T13:37:14+02:00",
         "url":"https://github.com/asf/asfasf/commit/ac7196c04ba24f180d37d77209ae92d38ee9c222",
         "author":{
            "name":"myname",
            "email":"email",
            "username":"username"
         },
         "committer":{
            "name":"GitHub",
            "email":"noreply@github.com",
            "username":"web-flow"
         },
         "added":[
            
         ],
         "removed":[
            
         ],
         "modified":[
            "x.txt"
         ]
      },
{
         "id":"ac7196c04ba24f180d37d77209ae92d38ee9c111",
         "tree_id":"9a4abe48ace9e76d561be86ae822a39ff2342345",
         "distinct":false,
         "message":"Merge pull merge request #14 from x",
         "timestamp":"2022-11-21T13:37:14+02:00",
         "url":"https://github.com/asf/asfasf/commit/12313235235325",
         "author":{
            "name":"myname",
            "email":"email",
            "username":"username"
         },
         "committer":{
            "name":"GitHub",
            "email":"noreply@github.com",
            "username":"web-flow"
         },
         "added":[
            
         ],
         "removed":[
            
         ],
         "modified":[
            "x.txt"
         ]
      }]
```

But, I have several questions:

1. I have no idea which one represents a merge from another branch - which is something I want to capture (if a PR made from branch A to branch B, merged to branch B, then B merged to main - i want to get the original PR aswell)
2. I've looked into the pull requests API (https://api.github.com/repos/myname/repo/pulls?state=all) - it seems that i need to pull everything, then try to understand by various commits if it's a relevant to a specific PR.

is there any cleaner way to do it?